# Instagram post from IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone

It is possible to post image/video direct to Instagram without using iphone hooks? I want to post image/video in background. When i am using the UIDocumentInteractionController, it redirect to Instagram native app. It is possible to post in background from my IOS app?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, you can only send images to Instagram via DocumentInteractionController.

If you look the list of [endpoints](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), there are no post functions for the media, but only for comments.

Answer (score 0):

> You can only read data from Instagram API. It doesn't allow you to
>   write on.

*Hipstamatic has negotiated special deals to use this kind of features.*

So you need to use iOS Hooks to post image/video on Instagram.

Comment: no, the user must be rooted to DocumentInteractionController